# PHP: cURL or header - faster and better way to send cross domain data and redirect

Tags: php, curl, header, cross-domain

I create one small API what collect contact form informations from one website and store in database on another website in managment application what I also build.

On website where is contact form is this code:

```
// collect all fields
$save = array(
    'oAuth'=>'{KEY}',
    'secret'=>'{SECRET-KEY}',
    'category'=>'Category',
    'name'=>'Jon Doe',
    'email'=>'jon@doe.com',
    'phone'=>'123 456 7890',
    // ... etc. other fields
);

// made GET request
$fields=array();
foreach($save as $key=>$val){
    $fields[]=$key."=".rawurlencode($val);
}

// Set cross domain URL
$url='http://api.mydomain.com/';

// Send informations in database
$cURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.join("&",$fields));
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
$output=curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);

usleep(1000);

// redirect
header("Location: http://somemysite.com/thank-you-page");
session_destroy();
exit;
```

My question is do to use cURL like now for this or to use `header()` function to send GET?

I ask because I not use output here and sometimes redirection start before cURL finish request.

What is faster way to send GET info and not lost data?

Answer (score 0):

The redirection *will not* start before cURL finishes. What may happen is that cURL fails to load you remote page, and you don't handle that error. You should add something like this:

```
if($output === false || curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200) {
   // Here you handle your error
}
```

If you are looking for an alternative to load remote webpages, you can set *allow_url_fopen* to true in your php.ini and then use this simple function instead of cURL:

```
$output = file_get_contents($url.'?'.join("&",$fields));
```